# re-assign vim buffer number

Tags: vim, buffer

I have vim buffers like this:

```
1 "file1.txt"
2 "file2.txt"
3 "file3.txt"
```

and I want re-assign buffer numbers like this:

```
1 "file2.txt"
2 "file1.txt"
3 "file3.txt"
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `:help :ls`:

> Each buffer has a unique number. 
>   That number will not change,      so you
>   can always go to a specific buffer
>   with ":buffer N" or       "N CTRL-^",
>   where N is the buffer number.

Why do you need to reassign those numbers? Maybe there is another thing to do to help you in your task?

Comment: I don't use windows and i don't use tabs in vim. I use buffers for manipulating files which I am editing. 
Maybe there ares some other ways to do this in vim?

Comment: Maybe you could harvest from the BufExplorer plug-in, or from `:args` and `:argdo` commands, from windowing and tabbing. All of them.

Comment: I am new with vim. And I do not use plug-ins yet. I want to learn standard vim commands and functions.

Comment: If you are new you should take time to learn, it won't be done in a single day! You can find vim geeks on IRC Freenode server (`#vim` channel) who will be happy to help you for any problem you might have.

Comment: You can use tab-completion in command mode, like :b <tab>. Wildmenu also improves greatly the completion (:set wildmode). With :b, tab-completion also works with substrings. With your example, :b 1<tab> will complete to file1.txt.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that you can't technically re-assign buffer numbers there is this plugin that allows you to act like you can:

https://github.com/gelus/vim-buffer-enhancement

it allows you to map buffers to numbers by hitting `<count><leader><C-6>`

Then returning to the mapped buffers in the same way you switch to a regular buffer `<count><C-6>`

so for your example:

- pull up file2.txt and hit `1<leader><C-6>`
- pull up file1.txt and hit `2<leader><C-6>`
- file3 is already at buffer 3, ( you can map it if you want, but it would work the same )
- now hitting `1<C-6>` will take you to file2.txt, `2<C-6>` will take you to file1.txt and `3<C-6>` will still take you to file3.txt